# How to run "larks" package

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am doing my master thesis on implementation of object detection techniques on GPU. For that I need to implement a method called lark. I found that code as a package "larks" in "object_recognition_experimental" stack. But i didn't understand how to run that package. I tried through various steps but i couldn't. And while i am trying to install dependencies using "rosdep install larks" i am getting an error

```
Failed to find rosdep libsoci for package larks on OS:ubuntu version:10.10 
ERROR: ABORTING: Rosdeps [u'libsoci'] could not be resolved
```

Could you please help me.

Thanks & Regards,

Venu Gande,
University of Klagenfurt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10001/how-to-run-%22larks%22-package/) by [venu_gandhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/561/venu_gandhe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the rosdep.yaml file for the object_recognition stack doesn't include a line for Ubuntu 10.10. A ticket should be filed against object_recognition [here](http://https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/query?component=object_recognition&status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened)  but until that gets fixed one workaround is to edit the rosdep.yaml file in the object_recognition stack root and duplicate the line which starts with 10.04, changing the 10.04 to 10.10.

When I did this and reran rosmake in the rein package I got an error about soci.h still not being found, but I fixed this by running make clean in the rein package folder and then rerunning rosmake. At that point I could successfully run rosmake larks.

---

Originally posted by [pbrook](https://answers.ros.org/users/226/pbrook/) with karma: 226 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1